# ora-01019 but not in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, oracle10g

I have a C# application running in Visual Studio 2010. When running it from Visual Studio (debug and release) it connects to an Oracle DB with no problems. When I attempt to run it outside of VS, I get an exception when it tries to connect.

The message is

"ORA-01019: unable to allocate memory in the user side."

I thought this may be something missing from the deployment project but I still get it when running the exe from the bin\release folder.

I've read that this error code can be caused by not having local admin privileges, but I am an admin. I have also seen that it can be caused by having multiple oracle clients but I only have Oracle 10g.

I'm running on Windows 7 x64 and have asked a co-worker with a similar machine (less VS2010) to try it and it connects fine on his machine (and also on an XP x86 machine).

The only other potentially relevant factor I can think of is that both my co-worker and myself have to work under the jackboot of Avecto Privilege Guard.

Please let me know if you'd like further information.

edit: If possible, I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require majorly tweaking my PC, but can be self-contained in the application so that other users don't experience the same problem.

Comment: Check you only have one Oracle home set.

Comment: I don't appear to have any oracle home set

Comment: What driver are you using?  ODP.net or managed ODP?

Comment: I'm not sure. How can I tell? All I know is that within the application the interface to the DB is done by System.Data.OleDb

Comment: On a second read, it may be something as simple as not having the DLLs copied to the release folder.  Check the folders as well -- sometimes there is an x86 and an x64 folder that need to be attached.  It can't hurt to switch to ODP.net and see if that resolves the matter -- it's actually a good choice for dealing with Oracle.

Comment: One other thing...  if you tnsping your server, maybe try using Oracle's ezConnect instead of the sever alias.  Tnsnames is great when it works and the devil when it doesn't

Comment: It's probably obvious that I'm maintaining this rather than developing but as far as I can tell the application is trying to be agnostic about the particular brand of DB as long as it is ODBC compliant, it connects to more than one DB (though not concurrently) so I would prefer to keep the libraries as generic as possible, but I will investigate ODP.net. I don't think there are any missing DLLs everything gets "ILMerge"d and it is communicating with oracle (but getting an error) rather than  failing to find the server. I'm not familiar with tnsping or ezConnect, so I'll do some googling. thx